# Converting CSV to ORC File Format

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, orc, azure-synapse

I have a file in BLOB storage which contains comma separated value. How to Convert this .txt file to ORC format.I am loading this data into Azure SQL DW and not using Java. Please share your thought on this one.

**Data**

```
A,B,C,
D,E,F,
```

File need to be converted to .txt to ORC format in BLOB storage.

Comment: Have you tried CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-as-select-transact-sql?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7

Comment: Thanks for your comment and This is my sample external table. CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].TEST
 (
   a                                varchar(150)          COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS             NOT NULL         
 )
 with (
 LOCATION='/TEST/a.txt',
 DATA_SOURCE=SIMPLE,
 FILE_FORMAT=TRANS_HEADER,
 REJECT_TYPE=VALUE,
 REJECT_VALUE=0
 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test_orc
WITH   
    (   
        LOCATION = '/TEST/a.orc',  
        DATA_SOURCE = SIMPLE,  
        FILE_FORMAT = TRANS_HEADER_ORC  
    )  
AS SELECT * FROM test
```

Comment: Thanks David, I have updated my question in another post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54580657/loading-orc-data-into-sql-dw-using-polybase