# Loading ORC Data into SQL DW using PolyBase

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse, polybase

I am trying to load ORC file format via PolyBase but I am facing below problems.

**Problem:1**

I have a CSV file which below code converts the csv file to ORC format but its selecting data from permanent table. If I remove **"as select * from dbo.test"** then create external table is not working. Permanent table contains 0 record.

```
 create external table test_orc
 with
 (
 location='/TEST/',
 DATA_SOURCE=SIMPLE,
 FILE_FORMAT=TEST_ORC
 )
 as select * from dbo.test ---Permanent Table
```

**Problem:2**

If I select the data from test_orc then I am getting invalid postscript error so, I removed my .csv file from the TEST directory. Is there any way to convert CSV to ORC  file in different directory like TEST2.

**Problem:3**

If I select the data from  test_orc then the count is zero and I am not getting any error.

```
select count(*) from test_orc---count is zero
```

**Expectation**

Need to load ORC file in the TEST directory to dbo.test table.

Please share your thought one this issue.

Comment: Watching your history of problems over the past couple of weeks, I think you are getting into deeper trouble. I shared my email address in another thread ... ron.dunn at Microsoft ... if you email me then we can take a more holistic approach to fixing all your load issues.

Comment: Thanks and I have sent you an email.